# is the structure of file XML good to Parse in JAVA

Tags: android, xml, dom

i have a file XML, i don't know the *structure is good or no*

**my problem:** I cann't get the ***certain sous_categories*** who belong to c***ategorie current***

for exemple: categorie with id_cat=1 ; i want to get the two sous_categorie 1 and 2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<categories>
    <categorie id_cat="1" titre="Tourisme">
        <sous_categorie id_sscat="1">
            <titre>Office de tourisme</titre>
            <description>Office de tourisme</description>
            <icone>http://www.testURL.fr/images/cat/restaurant.png</icone>
        </sous_categorie>
        <sous_categorie id_sscat="2" >
            <titre>Monuments/Site historique ou archéologique</titre>
            <description>Monuments/Site historique ou archéologique</description>
            <icone>http://www.testURL.fr/images/cat/museum-historical.png</icone>
        </sous_categorie>
    </categorie>
    <categorie id_cat="2" titre="Paysager">
        <sous_categorie id_sscat="6">
            <titre>Parc</titre>
            <description>Parc</description>
            <icone>http://www.testURL.fr/images/cat/park-urban.png</icone>
        </sous_categorie>
        <sous_categorie id_sscat="7">
            <titre>Réserve naturelle</titre>
            <description>Réserve naturelle</description>
            <icone>http://www.testURL.fr/images/cat/riparian.png</icone>
        </sous_categorie>
        <sous_categorie id_sscat="8">
            <titre>Site de loisir naturel ou aménagé</titre>
            <description>Site de loisir naturel ou aménagé</description>
            <icone>http://www.testURL.fr/images/cat/park.png</icone>
        </sous_categorie>
    </categorie>
    <categorie id_cat="3" titre="Arts et Culture">
        <sous_categorie id_sscat="10">
            <titre>Musée</titre>
            <description>Musée</description>
            <icone>http://www.testURL.fr/images/cat/museum.png</icone>
        </sous_categorie>       
    </categorie>
</categories>
```

thank you

Comment: You would probably get more responses if you had posed the entire question in English.

Comment: You also might want to work a little on your formatting of the question.

Comment: @sivakanesh - Since when is XML English? :)

Comment: @Jesus Ramos: my question, how can i get some sous_categorie of each categorie in Java ? if we can't get, what kind of new XML structure ? thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is not well formed. You have two top-level entities (and the first one is not terminated):

```
<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<categories>
    <!-- ... -->
</categories>
```

This should be rewritten:

```
<categories xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!-- ... -->
</categories>
```

Comment: i am agree with you about "the rewritten". But i have not found the method to parse the :some Sous_categorie that belong to categorie current. Thanks :)

Comment: How are you parsing the file now?

Comment: first time; i can parse the informations in categorie; for example: //get a nodelist of  elements
NodeList nl =docEle.getElementsByTagName("categorie");          //get the  element and get the Attribute
Element el = (Element)nl.item(i);                             String id_cat=empEl.getAttribute("id_cat");

Comment: Problem: with sous_categorie, i want parse only some sous_categories in this categorie parent !  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer

```
ArrayCategory=new ArrayList<Category>();
    //get the root element
    //2
    Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("categorie");
    //3
    if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
        //3.1

        for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength();i++) {
            //3.1               
            Element element_categorie = (Element)nl.item(i);
            //3.2               
            String id_cat=element_categorie.getAttribute("id_cat");
            String titreCat=element_categorie.getAttribute("titre");
            String uriicon = getTextValue(element_categorie,"icone");

            Category catTemp = new Category(id_cat, titreCat, uriicon);
            catTemp.vsousCat= new ArrayList<Sous_category>();

            //3.4
            //NodeList sscatList= e1.getElementsByTagName("sous_categorie");
            NodeList sousNodeList =     element_categorie.getElementsByTagName("sous_categorie");
            for(int j=0; j<sousNodeList.getLength();j++){
                //3.4.1
                Element sous_element_categorie = (Element) sousNodeList.item(j);
                //3.4.2
                String s_idcat = sous_element_categorie.getAttribute("id_sscat");
                String s_titre=         getTextValue(sous_element_categorie,"titre");
                String s_description=   getTextValue(sous_element_categorie,"description");
                String s_uriicon =      getTextValue(sous_element_categorie,"icone");

                Sous_category sous_catTemp = new Sous_category(s_idcat, s_titre, s_description, s_uriicon);

                //3.4.3 Ajouter SubCatTemp à Cate
                catTemp.vsousCat.add(sous_catTemp);
                //catTemp.sousCat.add(subTemp);
            }

            //add Category to the Arraylist of Category
            ArrayCategory.add(catTemp);
        }
    }
```